# Can not display alert message using PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have one issue while trying to display alert message using PHP.I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
if($id){
      $message = "Added successfully.";
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
      header("location:http://localhost/crm_complain/index.php");
  }else{
      $message = "Unable to add.\\nTry again.";
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
      header("location:http://localhost/crm_complain/index.php");
  }
?>
```

Here my problem is the alert message box is not working at all.I need inside the if/else condition the alert message should work.Please help me.

Comment: you need to call a function

Comment: how come you echo before sending out a header? Enable Error reporting...

Comment: You cannot print something and redirect using header. If PHP can send the header, the user won't see the printed message. So either redirection OR printing message.

Comment: if you want to alert, than y r u using header()??

Comment: If i am not redirecting to header the post data is submitting again again at each page reload.My aim is i have to display the alert message and then i will redirect to orginal page.

Answer (score 1):

The alert message works fine, but the header does not. 
If you want to redirect after the alert message, try this:

```
die('<script>location.href = "'. $url .'"</script>');
```

Comment: what this $url contains.

Comment: any url. you can of course also hard code it like this:
`die('<script>location.href = "page.html"</script>');`

Answer (score 0):

You can not get alert as like that because you are using header(). You can resolve this as:

**Your PHP Code (pass success status):**

```
<?php
if($id)
{
    //$message = "Added successfully.";
    header("location:http://localhost/crm_complain/index.php?success=1"); // success status
}
else
{
    //$message = "Unable to add.\\nTry again.";
    header("location:http://localhost/crm_complain/index.php?success=0"); // failure status
}
?>
```

**You need to add following code in index.php file for getting alerts:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var phpVar = "<?php if(isset($_GET['success'])) {echo $_GET['success'];} else { echo ""; } ?>";
    if(phpVar == 1){
        alert('Added successfully.');
    }
    else if(phpVar == 0){
        alert('Unable to add.\\nTry again.');   
    }
    else{
        // nothing
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @ devpro : But as per you each time of reload the else part alert is coming.

Comment: No,same issue but it resolved by checking `phpVar == 0 && phpVar!=' '`.